# How to make Gatsby Link receive props as parameter and turn off click cursor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a component wrapper to cut some repetitive code on my application.
This wrapper has some props, so I can choose if I want to print a text with an icon or an icon that is a link to another page.
My objective is to render text with an icon and the icon is not clickable as a link, but if I render just an icon the icon is clickable as link.

rowListComponent:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import PeopleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/People";
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemIcon from "@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default function RowListComponent(props) {
  const style = styles();

  return (
    <List className={style.listSize}>
      <ListItem className={style.listSize}>
        <Link to={`/${props.component}/${props.link}`}>
          <ListItemIcon>{props.icon}</ListItemIcon>
        </Link>
        <ListItemText>{props.name}</ListItemText>
      </ListItem>
    </List>
  );
}
```

I want to use this component wrapper on  another component and i use it like this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <MaterialTable
      icons={tableIcons}
      title={<h1 className={style.title}>Users</h1>}
      columns={[
        {
          title: "Name",
          field: "name",
          render: rowData => (
            <RowListComponent
              icon={<PeopleIcon className={style.iconColor} />}
              name={rowData.name}
            />
          )
        },
        {
          title: "Details",
          field: "details",
          render: rowData => (
            <RowListComponent
              icon={<ListAltIcon className={style.iconColor} />}
              component={"users"}
              link={rowData.details}
            />
          )
        }
      ]}
      data={state.users}
      options={{
        search: true
      }}
    />
  </div>
);
```

My problem is that I want to make the link active or not with a prop as well, so when you pass the mouse over the link the cursor does not change.

UPDATED:

I come with a solution but it's not what I want but it works.

```
export default function RowListComponent(props) {
  const style = styles();
  return (
    <List className={style.listSize}>
      <ListItem className={style.listSize}>
        <Link
          to={`/${props.component}/${props.link}`}
          className={props.isActive}
        >
          <ListItemIcon>{props.icon}</ListItemIcon>
        </Link>
        <ListItemText>{props.name}</ListItemText>
      </ListItem>
    </List>
  );
}
```

I set the isActive prop: `isActive = {style.disabledLink}` and this style is `pointerEvents: "none"` but what i really wanted was just to say `isActive = {true or false}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

`` <Link to={`/${props.component}/${props.link}`} className={`${props.isActive ? "is-active" : "not-active"}`}> ``

Now you can add css to the 'is-active' class that sets 'pointerEvents' to none. And you can pass a bool value to 'isActive'.

I have also seen [this](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) nice package to join conditional classnames. Then this would be the solution:

`` <Link to={`/${props.component}/${props.link}`} className={classNames({ 'is-active': props.isActive })}> ``

Or if you want to directly add the style without a classname:

`` <Link to={`/${props.component}/${props.link}`} style={{ pointerEvents: props.isActive ? 'none': 'auto'}}> ``